# Redirecting www.domain.com and domain.com to subdomain.domain.com using httpd

Tags: php, apache, http, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect:

Situation 1. `example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`

Situation 2. `www.example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`

I have put these 2 chunks of code inside my httpd.conf. Only Situation 2 is working, but not Situation 1.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/foo"
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
     <Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from All
     </Directory>
     Redirect permanent http://example.com/ http://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/foo"
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
     <Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from All
     </Directory>
     Redirect permanent / http://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's the PHP request?

Comment: @Forbs i already stated in the question, situation 1 and situation 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. Redirecting `example.com` and `www.example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`, then only set the document root of `subdomain.example.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
     Redirect permanent / http://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/foo"
     ServerName subdomain.example.com
     ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
     <Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

By using these codes in httpd.conf, I am able to:

1. Redirect `example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`
2. Redirect `www.example.com` to `subdomain.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/foo"
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com

     <Directory "/var/www/html/foo">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
                Options +ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from All
     </Directory>

     Redirect permanent / http://subdomain.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you try to copy the 2nd situation and paste it to replace 1st situation and then removing the www on the example.com?

Comment: yes, i will receive example.com or subdomain.example.com `has redirected you too many times` error. if i enter www.example.com the link becomes invalid